# php variable used as mysqli column name syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, mysqli

This is where I think it´s the problem...

```
$sql1 = "SELECT `puntos_globales`, '$juego' 
         FROM `lista_jugadores` WHERE `id_jugador`='$noTop'";
```

This is the error message:

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "blackOps2'='1' WHERE `id_jugador` = '10" at line 1
```

$juego .. is a php variable that holds the column name; in this case blackOps2. I don´t know why in the error says blackOps2'='1'??

Comment: the error is not same as your query , please provide your true query

Comment: `'` turns things into a strings and removes any "significance" they might have to the database. `foo` would be a field/table name, `'foo'` is just a string that contains the word `foo`.

Comment: You did use backticks for one column name but apostrophes for another. What was your reason?

Comment: **Never use backticks around column names.**  They are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea as well, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about having a syntax error explained.

Comment: @AndyLester what? Where did you get that idea on not using backticks?

Comment: What is unclear about my statement?  What value do you see in using backticks around column names?

Comment: I already try with backticks o without them...I try with apostophes and tithou them in $juego and curly brackets...and keep same error. Why appear that the column name $juego is = 1 (blackOps2=1)?

Comment: @AndyLester backticks are part of proper formatting rules for identifiers. While proper formatting is a cornerstone of syntactical correctness and safety, mind you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Who says that "backticks are part of proper formatting rules for identifiers"?  What value is there in unnecessary punctuation?

Comment: @AndyLester as unreliable source as mysql manual, sir.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Would love to see a citation in the manual that says there is value in putting unnecessary punctuation around table or column names.

Comment: @AndyLester indeed there is no value in adding backticks alone. But in combination with escaping backticks it become indispensable in the matter of adding dynamical identifiers to the query

Answer (score 0):

from the error it seems you didnt provide the true query and it looks you have two where clause

```
     blackOps2='1' WHERE `id_jugador` = '10"
```

try do it like that

```
     WHERE `id_jugador` = '10' AND blackOps2='1'
```

Comment: blackOps2 is a column name that $juego holds...I don´t know why the error says that...

Comment: even what you said but its not the same query in the error message. where you have `='1'` ? and before WHERE you have table name not `$juego`. either you providing wrong query or you the query is colled with something else.

Comment: thanks to you I could find the problem. The problem was in the next line: $sql2 = "UPDATE `lista_jugadores` SET `puntos_globales`='$ptsG', '$juego'='$ptsJ' WHERE `id_jugador`='$noTop'; "; The apostrophes around $juego was the problem... Thanks, I am a novice in this...